# elmah.bootstrapper errors Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I am using elmah.bootstrapper v1.0.1 in my ASP.Net MVC v5 project. Have the following key in web.config -

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="elmah:web:path" value="/admin/errors" />
</appSettings>
<elmah>
   <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
</elmah>
```

It works well in local host. But after hosted in real server, I can not access the errors page. It said -

```
Forbidden: Access is denied.
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: You may need to set up a user or role in web config to get access. https://elmah.github.io/a/securing-error-log-pages/

Comment: Can you publish your entire web.config?